# How to convert Video CD (VCD) into mp3 or other audio format?

Tags: conversion, mp3, file-format, vcd

I've a stack of music VCDs which I'd like to be able to listen to on my mp3 player.

Any suggestions for the best tool to do the conversion? Preferably on windows, and free or open source.

Answer (score 2):

**[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)** (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) makes ripping audio tracks from video files a breeze (you may have to rename avseqxx.dat to avseqxx.mpeg).

*SUPER © is freeware.*

Answer (score 0):

All the products below are free and require [LAME Encoder](http://www.free-codecs.com/Lame_Encoder_download.htm) to encode MP3.

[Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/)
Handles CD imperfections and scratches with ease.

[CDex](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/)
Capable of transcoding one file format to another

[Audiograbber](http://www.audiograbber.com-us.net/)
Interface is very intuitive, very small size for its features
Appears to be abandonware, runs very quirky on Vista.

Comment: Oh, EAC can rip from a Video CD? didn't know that.

Comment: these only rip from VCDs that include CDDA audio tracks.  if the OP is looking to extract the audio from the VCD's MPEG video, Handbrake is the better option.  VCD info: http://www.videohelp.com/vcd#tech2

Answer (score 0):

I think [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) can do this -- have not tried it though.